# Difference between "attended to by" and "attended by"

Tags: differences, phrase-meaning

In following, what are the differences between these two sentences?

- I was ***attended to*** by a specialist doctor.
- I was ***attended*** by a specialist doctor.

Comment: _Attend_ may be used transitively (_A specialist doctor attended me_), or intransitively with a transitivizing preposition _to_ and a special sense of responsibility and competence (_A specialist doctor attended to me_). Both sentences can be passivized, yielding the two sentences above.

Comment: Note that if you didn't say "I was", then the general reading would say "attended" as an event, and "attended to" as "being taken care of."

Answer (score 1):

Structurally:
*Attend to* is indirect, which is to say the preposition "to" is non-trivial; *attend*  is direct. Note that in both cases there is an object (called either an indirect (with preposition) or direct (without preposition) object).

Rhetorically: These two things don't actually mean the same thing (necessarily). They are never interchangeable. *Attend to* is simpler: this is to *take care of* or to *see to*, and the object is typically a task or person, or an object which implies a task ("Please *attend to* the garbage"). *Attend*, on the other hand, is almost always used to describe appearing at an event, i.e. "I will *attend* the wedding". HOWEVER there are several other archaic uses, including "wait for/on " and "take heed of " -- these are the origins of the phrase "pay attention to" and a person who is "an attendant".

Answer (score 0):

***Attended*** is the verb usage *with* an object, while ***attended to*** is the verb usage *without* an object.